# update table in oracle using conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a source table A with below values

```
Source A:

id, r_dt        cancel_dt
1   null         null
2   null         04-10-2018
3   04-08-2018   null
3   04-09-2018   null
3   null         null 

Target B  

id, t_dt 
1   04-09-2018
2   04-09-2018
3   04-08-2018
```

on a given day, we may get duplicate values from source and we need to apply some conditons to update target

so for eg: we have to group the data using loan_id 
if we get null r_dt and null c_dt then we do nothing

if we get null dt row with cancel dt and r_dt row with out cancel_dt then 
pick r_dt value and update to tgt.

if we get 2 r_dt rows after group by then do max value of r_dt

how can i come up with this logic in oracle sql

please guide me

Comment: Your explanation does not agree with your sample target table. You said for id=1 di nothing but there is id=1 in target table. if r dt is null and canel dt is not null then use cancel dt but id=2 ia apr 9 instead of apr 10. for more than one id, you said MAX r dt but you put min.  why???

Answer (score 0):

Please try below, I can't verify this:

Update b
Set t_dt=(select decode(r_dt is null and cancel_dt is not null,null,r_dt is not null, Max(r_dt) ) from a where a.id=b.id)

Comment: Thank you Sunil. if i get r_dt as null and cancel_dt is not null then i update t_dt to null. So for id 2 in tgt the date should be update to null

Comment: why dont you update your sample target table? all of them are not correct based on your explanation